# Can we manipulate elements which has been faded out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some buttons on the page which are faded out by default and will be visible only when the user will click on the page content. This is working just fine.

I am now in the need to assign some data attribute to one of this buttons just before the user will click on the content making them visible.

It is possible to point to the faded element and add the needed data attribute?

All my attempts were unsuccessful.

Any help with this will be appreciated.

EDIT:

```
<div class="ui-draggable">
    <div id="119a7" class="container template-block drg-elem">
        <div class="row clearfix drg ui-sortable" contenteditable="true">
            <div class="column col-md-6">
                <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
                <div class="row-arrange ui-sortable-handle">
                    <div class="btn-xs arrange-handle">
                        <i class="fa fa-arrows"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column col-md-6">
                <img src="assets/builder/images/e09-1.jpg">
                <div class="row-arrange ui-sortable-handle">
                    <div class="btn-xs arrange-handle">
                        <i class="fa fa-arrows"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tool-box">
        <div class="row-settings">
            <i class="fa fa-wrench"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There is nothing special in here. This is a template which is dropped on the `html page`.

The `tool-box` is the element in question which is faded out.

I have tried to refer to this element but it can not be found.

How can I refer to an invisible element?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Please [edit] your question to show the code that didn't work.

Comment: have you remove the element after the element fade out?if not you can,otherwise can't.

Answer (score 2):

have you remove the element after the element fade out?if not you can,otherwise can't.

```js
$.extend($.fn, {
    fill: function () {
        return this.data('foo', 'bar');
    },
    inspect: function () {
        console.log(this.data('foo'));
        return this;
    }
});
$('button').click(function () {
    $('main div')[this.id]();
});
```

```css
main div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #333;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="fadeOut">Fade Out</button>
<button id="remove">Remove</button>
<button id="fill">Fill Data</button>
<button id="inspect">Inspect</button>
<main><div></div></main>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I have a feeling that I didn't explain the problem correctly. The `tool-box` is by default faded out so it is invisible on the page. I need to add a data attribute to this `tool-box' and I have tried a few dozen of solutions, but nothing works. So the question is how I can point to an invisible element. Thanks

Comment: my answer can do,you try all buttons in sequence: fadeOut > fill data > inspect > remove >inspect.then you know that can set data on a invisible dom if not removed from the dom

Comment: how  to point an invisible element?using [jquery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) instead.there is a [:hidden](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/visibility-filter-selectors/) selector for you.

Comment: I will try to implement this in my plugin. I will let you know if it will work. Thanks

Comment: looking at my plugin code I have found that I was forgotten to apply the click behavior to the `row-settings`. So I have fortunately fixed the issue. For your effort and because your answer could be useful for someone else I will accept it. Thanks again